# Collecting the Async results as they become available

Tags: multithreading, haskell, asynchronous

How would you collect the results of a list of `Async a` in Haskell ***as they become available***? The idea is to start processing the results of asynchronous tasks as soon as they are available.

The best I could come up with is the following function:

```
collect :: [Async a] -> IO [a]
collect [] = return []
collect asyncs = do
  (a, r) <- waitAny asyncs
  rs <- collect (filter (/= a) asyncs)
  return (r:rs)
```

However, this function does not exhibits the desired behavior since, as pointed out in the comment below, it doesn't return till all the asynchronous tasks are completed. Furthermore, `collect` runs in `O(n^2)` since I'm filtering the list at each recursive step. This could be improved by using a more efficient structure (and maybe indexing the position of the `Async` values in the list).

Maybe there are library functions that take care of this, but I could not find them in the `Control.Concurrent.Async` module and I wonder why.

***EDIT***: after thinking the problem a bit more carefully, I'm wondering whether such function is a good idea. I could just use `fmap` on the asynchronous tasks. Maybe it is a better practice to wait for the results when there is no other choice.

Comment: Your `collect` doesn't return until all the `Async`s in the list have completed. Is that what you're after?

Comment: No. I didn't realized that. My implementation is indeed wrong. My idea was having `collect` return a result as soon as the asynchronous thread is ready. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38813404/1523776), streaming results out of a list of `Async`s as they become available is best achieved using a stream processing library. Here's an example using [`pipes`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes).

```
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
import Control.Concurrent.Async
import Control.Concurrent.STM
import Data.Functor (($>))
import Pipes
import Pipes.Concurrent  -- from the pipes-concurrency package
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P


asCompleted :: MonadIO m => [Async a] -> Producer a m ()
asCompleted asyncs = do
    (o, i, seal) <- liftIO $ spawn' unbounded
    liftIO $ forkIO $ do
        forConcurrently asyncs (\async -> atomically $ waitSTM async >>= send o)
        atomically seal
    fromInput i

main = do
    actions <- traverse async [threadDelay 2000000 $> "bar", threadDelay 1000000 $> "foo"]
    runEffect $ asCompleted actions >-> P.print
-- after one second, prints "foo", then "bar" a second later
```

Using [`pipes-concurrency`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-concurrency), we [`spawn'`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-concurrency-2.0.6/docs/Pipes-Concurrent.html#v:spawn-39-) an [`Output`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-concurrency-2.0.6/docs/Pipes-Concurrent.html#t:Output)-[`Input`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-concurrency-2.0.6/docs/Pipes-Concurrent.html#t:Input) pair and immediately convert the `Input` to a [`Producer`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.2.0/docs/Pipes.html#t:Producer) using [`fromInput`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-concurrency-2.0.6/docs/Pipes-Concurrent.html#v:fromInput). Asynchronously, we [`send`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-concurrency-2.0.6/docs/Pipes-Concurrent.html#v:send) items as they become available. When all the `Async`s have completed we `seal` the inbox to close down the `Producer`.

Answer (score 1):

Implemented via `TChan`, additionally implemented a version which can react immediately, but it is more complex and also might have problems with exceptions (if you want to receive exceptions, use `SlaveThread.fork` instead of `forkIO`), so I commented that code in case you're not interested in it:

```
import           Control.Concurrent       (threadDelay)
import           Control.Concurrent       (forkIO)
import           Control.Concurrent.Async
import           Control.Concurrent.STM
import           Control.Monad

collect :: [Async a] -> IO [a]
collect = atomically . collectSTM

collectSTM :: [Async a] -> STM [a]
collectSTM as = do
    c <- newTChan
    collectSTMChan c as

collectSTMChan :: TChan a -> [Async a] -> STM [a]
collectSTMChan chan as = do
    mapM_ (waitSTM >=> writeTChan chan) as
    replicateM (length as) (readTChan chan)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    a1 <- async (threadDelay 2000000 >> putStrLn "slept 2 secs" >> return 2)
    a2 <- async (threadDelay 3000000 >> putStrLn "slept 3 secs" >> return 3)
    a3 <- async (threadDelay 1000000 >> putStrLn "slept 1 sec" >> return 1)
    res <- collect [a1,a2,a3]
    putStrLn (show res)

    -- -- reacting immediately
    -- a1 <- async (threadDelay 2000000 >> putStrLn "slept 2 secs" >> return 2)
    -- a2 <- async (threadDelay 3000000 >> putStrLn "slept 3 secs" >> return 3)
    -- a3 <- async (threadDelay 1000000 >> putStrLn "slept 1 sec" >> return 1)
    -- c <- collectChan [a1,a2,a3]
    -- replicateM_ 3 (atomically (readTChan c) >>= \v -> putStrLn ("Received: " ++ show v))

-- collectChan :: [Async a] -> IO (TChan a)
-- collectChan as = do
--     c <- newTChanIO
--     forM_ as $ \a -> forkIO ((atomically . (waitSTM >=> writeTChan c)) a)
--     return c
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading your question as "is it possible to sort a list of `Async`s by their completion time?". If that's what you meant, the answer is yes.

```
import Control.Applicative (liftA2)
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
import Control.Concurrent.Async
import Data.Functor (($>))
import Data.List (sortBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)
import Data.Time (getCurrentTime)


sortByCompletion :: [Async a] -> IO [a]
sortByCompletion = fmap (fmap fst . sortBy (comparing snd)) . mapConcurrently withCompletionTime
    where withCompletionTime async = liftA2 (,) (wait async) getCurrentTime

main = do
    asyncs <- traverse async [threadDelay 2000000 $> "bar", threadDelay 1000000 $> "foo"]
    sortByCompletion asyncs
-- ["foo", "bar"], after two seconds
```

Using `mapConcurrently` we wait for each `Async` on a separate thread. Upon completion we get the current time - the time at which the `Async` completed - and use it to sort the results. This is O(n log n) complexity because we are sorting the list. (Your original algorithm was effectively a [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).)

Like your `collect`, `sortByCompletion` doesn't return until all the `Async`s in the list have completed. If you wanted to *stream* results onto the main thread as they become available, well, lists aren't a very good tool for that. I'd use a streaming abstraction like [`conduit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit) or [`pipes`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes), or, working at a lower level, a [`TQueue`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-2.4.4.1/docs/Control-Concurrent-STM-TQueue.html). See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38813892/1523776) for an example.

Comment: I do not want to sort the `Async` values by completion time, but be able to start processing as soon as a result becomes available. Thanks for pointing this out. I'll add this clarification to my question.